# Derivation of an estimate for CDF given ordered sample

Tags: estimation, sample, order-statistics

Given a sample $x_1,\ldots,x_n$ one may order them $x_{(1)},\ldots,x_{(n)}$ and an estimate for the CDF $P(X\leq x_{(i)})$ is $\frac{i}{n}$ which is valid given that the CDF of a sample is uniform. However, the text I'm reading claims the following estimate to be a valid (and better) estimate for the CDF

> $$
> P(X\leq x_{(i)}) \approx \frac{i-\frac{3}{8}}{n+\frac{1}{4}}
> $$

but it doesn't explain how to derive this estimate, so I was wondering how this estimate can be found?

The text later assumes $x_i$ to be normally distributed, if that is of relevance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer after searching the web: This is due to Blom (1954), who used a general estimate for the empirical distribution function given by

> $$
> P(X\leq x_{(i)}) = F(x_{(i)}) \approx \hat{F}_n(x_{(i)}) = \frac{i-\alpha}{n+1-2\alpha}
> $$

where $\alpha \in [0,0.5]$. He attempted to find $\alpha$ by solving
$$
\operatorname{E}(x_{(i)}) = \Phi^{-1}\left(\frac{i-\alpha}{n+1-2\alpha}\right)
$$

which yields

$$
\alpha_{i,n} = \frac{1-(n+1)\Phi(E(x_{(i)})}{1-2\Phi(E(x_{(i)})}
$$

Blom conjectured this value to lie in the interval $(0.33,0.5)$ which he found was true for small $n$, so a good compromise was $0.375$, or $3/8$. Inserting this value for $\alpha$ in the original estimate yields

> $$
> \hat{F}_n(x) = \frac{i-3/8}{n+1/4}
> $$

Sources:

1. [CRC Handbook of Tables for the Use of Order Statistics in Estimation](https://books.google.no/books?id=-g1e4-FlAcEC&pg=PA34&lpg=PA34&dq=blom%27s+formula+1954&source=bl&ots=-PG4xN2BNn&sig=US3PapauhtQ_VBgIbKGzmWzOWB8&hl=no&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjxj9eAtJHZAhXLhywKHac4BS0Q6AEITTAM#v=onepage&q=blom's%20formula%201954&f=false)
2. [Impact of Rank-Based Normalizing Transformations on the Accuracy of Test Scores](https://digitalcommons.wayne.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?referer=https://www.google.no/&httpsredir=1&article=1004&context=coe_tbf)